# How to process onmessage event data from websocket

Tags: javascript, json, websocket, vert.x

I'm setting up a vert.x project in which I'm sending a snippet of JSON from my Java based server to a javascript client via websocket.

Vert.x server sending the JSON:

```
        vertx.eventBus().send("mongodb-persistor", collectionsQuery, new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Message<JsonObject> data) {
                container.logger().info(data.body().encodePrettily());
                ws.write(new Buffer(data.body().toString()));
            }

        });
```

The data being sent as outputted on the console:

> {
>     "collections" : [ "AAPL", "AZN", "GOOG", "YHOO", "system.indexes" ],
>     "status" : "ok"
>   }

When i receive this on the client:

```
    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    alert("Received data from websocket: " + event.data);
    var x = JSON.parse(event.data);
};
```

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o (index):124socket.onmessage

I've read up and it appears as though that's because the JSON has already been parsed. So if I don't parse the JSON, how do i actually access my data? If i just output event.data as string, all I get is the type and size as opposed to the data logged on the console.

EDIT:
I also get the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with status 404" off the following line /sometimes/, even though event.data is still populated with the correct message size.

> alert("Received data from websocket: " + event.data);

Any help is appreciated and I hope this information is self contained enough!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in vert.x I shouldn't be returning the JSON wrapped in a Buffer.

Instead I used the method [writeTextFrame](http://vertx.io/api/clojure/vertx.http.websocket.html)

```
        vertx.eventBus().send("mongodb-persistor", collectionsQuery, new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Message<JsonObject> data) {
            container.logger().info(data.body().toString());
            ws.writeTextFrame(data.body().encode());
        }

    });
```